# How to organize the associative array [ php] in visual studio code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, associative-array

I want to organize this array...
What is the easiest way to do that?
Thank you very much for your valuable time and excuse my language

```
 [
   'dashboard' => 'Dashboard',
    'languages'    => 'Languages',
    'home' => 'Home',
    'profile' => 'Profile',
    'notifications' => 'Notifications',
    'alerts' => 'Alerts',
]
```

to be....

```
[
   'dashboard'      => 'Dashboard',
    'languages'     => 'Languages',
    'home'          => 'Home',
    'profile'       => 'Profile',
    'notifications' => 'Notifications',
    'alerts'        => 'Alerts',
]
```

Comment: You can try using prettier extension. But, tabs should work for this. (I meant to put a comment. Accidentally answered it!)

Comment: Thanks, Santhosh J
but prettier extension don't work with me